# Error - easeInBounce is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easing

I am attempting to use jQuery easing function `easeInBounce` and I see this error:

```
ReferenceError: easeInBounce is not defined
```

I am using jQuery 1.8, Easing 1.3 and jQuery UI 1.8.23.

Here is my code

***HTML:***

```
 <div id="loading">
<h2 class="textcenter">Loading...</h2>
 <img id="loading-image" class="center" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif"  />
</div>
<div id="content-wrap" class="hide">
    <div class="img-center">
    <img style="z-index:10" src="/bird-bg.jpg" />
    </div>
    <img class="hide" id="bird" src="/bird.png" />
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
#bird{
position:absolute;
left:300px;
top: 0px;
z-index:999;
}

.hide {display: none;}
```

***JS:***

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
   $j(window).load(function() {
        $j('#loading').fadeOut('slow', function() {
  $j("#content-wrap").fadeIn("slow", function() {
      $j("#bird").slideDown({ duration: 1000, easing: easeInBounce});
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: How about quoting the `easeInBounce` string! => `{ duration: 1000, easing: "easeInBounce"}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript engine things easeInBounce is a variable name. So you either have to define it or put it in quotes as a string.

```
  $j("#bird").slideDown({ duration: 1000, easing: 'easeInBounce'});
```

Look at the quotes I added. It should work as a string.

Without the quotes you would have had to define the variable as the sample below, which does the same as adding the quotes as above.

```
  var easeInBounce = 'easeInBounce'; //This would be anywhere before the line where you add the ease in animation
```

Hope this helps. Thanks